# Div change size when other screen resolution

Tags: html, css, screen, resolution

i was making site and added div to left, but when i change screen, (other resolution) the div will go smaller? Any solutions?

CSS:

```
#chat {
width:15%;
height:86.4%;
background: #232b32;
color:#000;
margin-top: -1.5%;


.chat-online {
width: 100%;
height: 5%;
background: #232b32;
font-family: Prototype;
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
color:#fff;
```

HTMl:

```
 <div id="chat">
    <div class="chat-online">Chat (1)
        </div>
```

Comment: Ofcourse the div will get smaller when you use %percentage to specify width. To keep a fixed width, specify you width in pixels. For exaple width:150px;

Answer (score 0):

You are using width: 15%, that means 15 of the father if the father doesn't have a fixed with it will change wen the window change.

Comment: Lol, Think these elements are called parent-element :P

Comment: Fix the width, that the solution, try to calculate how many px do you wanna have, and use them instead of %. And @FrankW. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is based on the way you designed your site using percentages. Percentages are part of a fluid layout. Pixels are the standard for a "fixed" layout. What you trying to accomplish is a fixed layout. Instead of using % for the width and height of your chat elements, use pixels.

For example. Instead of >

```
#chat {
 width:15%;
 height:86.4%;
 background: #232b32;
 color:#000;
 margin-top: -1.5%;
 } 


.chat-online {
 width: 100%;
 height: 5%;
 background: #232b32;
 font-family: Prototype;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 26px;
 color:#fff;
 }
```

Use something like >

```
#chat {
 width:30px;
 height:200px;
 background: #232b32;
 color:#000;
 margin-top: -1.5%;
 } 


.chat-online {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 50px;
 background: #232b32;
 font-family: Prototype;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 26px;
 color:#fff;
 }
```

Of course those are just random numbers but you get the idea. You might have to play around with different numbers to get the exact look you are heading for.